# Best python data structure for network device properties

Tags: python

I'm really seeking some expert opinions.  I want to discover all the devices on a network and store their mgmt IP's and interface name and IP's so I can call them.

The question I have is around the most efficient structure to store the info.  Is a dict of dicts the best way?

So my plan is to have a dict like:

```
devices = {'dev1': {'mgmt_v4': '192.168.0.1',
                    'mgmt_v6': '192::1',
                    'interfaces': {'g0/0_v4': '10.10.10.1',
                                   'g0/0_v6': '10::1',
                                   'g0/1_v4': '20.20.20.2',
                                   'g0/1_v6': '20::2'}}}
```

While I'm not sure there's anything wrong with doing it this way, how would other people handle it in python?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your definition of efficiency? Least memory used?

Comment: Efficiency as in accessibility and ease of use inside the program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dicts are a very flexible tool and they are good for fast prototyping. But they are too flexible: it is easy to misstype key value and you lack a good reference how exactly you have named your keys. In your structure you have two places where keys will be arbitrary:

- Device name to device properties mapping
- Interface name to IP address mapping

Dicts are a natural way to express them. But device properties have fixed key set: `mgmt_v4`, `mvmt_v6` and `interfaces`. It is better to defince a class with theese fields.

```
class DeviceProperties(object):
    def __init__(self, mgmt_v4, mgmt_v6, interfaces):
        self.mgmt_v4 = mgmt_v4
        self.mgmt_v6 = mgmt_v6
        self.interfaces = interfaces
```

Then you will store them as

```
{
"dev1" : DeviceProperties(
    '192.168.0.1',
    '192::1', 
    {
        'g0/0_v4': '10.10.10.1',
        'g0/0_v6': '10::1',
        'g0/1_v4': '20.20.20.2',
        'g0/1_v6': '20::2'
    })
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Alexey, that seems like it might be a better way to handle it.  I'll check it out.